# MySQL Federated Tables Escaped Table Names

Tags: mysql, url, jdbc, federated

I am trying to use MySQL federated tables. The problem is that the documentation specified at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html says that a federated table should be created using the following format for the CONNECTION parameter:

```
scheme://user_name[:password]@host_name[:port_num]/db_name/tbl_name
```

E.G.

```
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database/tablename'
CONNECTION='mysql://username@hostname/database/tablename'
CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname/database/tablename'
```

The problem is that the table I am trying to connect to has non-standard characters in it and I cannot find the proper way to scape them in the connections tring.

For example, a table named `Table (one)` . Which has the space and the parenthesis, requiring backticks surrounding it inside any SQL code.

Anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a bit late, and I don't even know if it will work, but since the connection string is a URL, can you escape it the way you would a URL?  i.e. Table%20%28one%29